# Ignore some parametrizations of a fixture in a test

Tags: pytest

I have a component which can cooperate with two different databases, and in two different modes, with slight differences in functionality depending on which database and which mode is used. I have a battery of tests which, in general, should be run for each combination of database/mode, but there some tests that will work only for 3 of 4 combinations.

My integration tests are modeled as follows: I have parameterized fixtures that provide a database connection and a component initialized in a given mode. Then each tests taking these fixtures is naturally run for each combination:

```
import pytest

class TestMyComponent(object):
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True, params=['sqlite', 'postgresql'])
    def database(self, request):
        if request.param == 'sqlite':
            return 'Opened in-memory sqlite connection'
        else:
            return 'Opened postgresql connection'

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True, params=['live', 'batch'])
    def component(self, request):
        if request.param == 'live':
            return 'Component initialized in a live mode'
        else:
            return 'Component initialized in a batch mode'

    def test_empty_db_has_no_items(self):
        assert True  # all four tests pass

    def test_stream_new_items(self, database, mode):
        # we don't want to test streaming with sqlite and live mode
        assert 'postgresql' in database or 'batch' in mode
```

What is the best way to have py.test not run tests for the unsupported combinations?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like raising a test skip for forbidden combination solves your problem. E.g.

```
def test_stream_new_items(self, database, mode):
    # we don't want to test streaming with sqlite and live mode
    if 'sqlite' in database and 'live' in mode:
        pytest.skip("streaming with sqlite and live mode is not supported"
    assert 'postgresql' in database or 'batch' in mode
```

Comment: So, the test will be executed, but marked as skipped?

Comment: Yes. Another way is using `pytest_generate_tests` hook like I did for [aiopg test suite](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiopg/blob/master/tests/conftest.py#L101-L110) but maybe it's overcompication for your case.

Comment: Hmm, given that I'll have quite a lot of these tests and more than two dimensions, I might try the `pytest_generate_tests` route. Could you add it to the answer, preferably pointing out drawbacks and advantages of both solutions? (btw, the aiopg example is very nice, thanks for linking it)